# erro referencia .net 4.6.1 para o .netStandart 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Estou com um problema ao referenciar uma um projeto Standart2.0 a minha api .net Framework 461;

ocorre o seguinte tenho a classe:

```
public class MeuReturn : IHttpActionResult
{
        private readonly string _objeto;

        public MeuReturn(string objeto)
        {
            _objeto = objeto;
        }
        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = 
                                        new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(_objeto)
            };
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }

}
```

para efetuar um retorno personalizado, funciona 100% mas quando referencio o outro projeto e rodo a API ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Ocorreu um erro.  Método
>   ExecuteAsync no tipo WebApplication3.Controllers.MeuReturn do assembly
>   WebApplication3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>   não tem uma implementação. 
>   System.TypeLoadException 
>   em WebApplication3.Controllers.HomeController.erro() em
>   lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) em
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters) em
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments) em
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior
>   onde a exceção foi gerada --- em
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) em
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) em
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada --- em
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) em
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) em
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada --- em
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) em
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) em
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

verifiquei novamente o [site da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/net-standard) e teoricamente são compatíveis

Comment: Este código faz parte de qual projeto? Qual deles está sendo referenciado em qual?

Comment: .net 4.6.1 referencia .net standard 2.0 
este projeto é o problema isolado. o problema real ocorre um um projeto grande porem, este caso apresentado ocorre em um projeto com praticamente em branco com somente esta classe uma controller um metodo. E o outro projeto .net standard Default(com o class1 e tudo). para isolar o erro; caso queira posso disponibilizar o codigo;

Comment: João, sinceramente eu fiquei um pouco confuso. Vamos tentar por partes. O código que você mostra na pergunta está uma _class library_ .NET Standard 2.0?

Comment: Vamos lá: o código em amostra eh uma classe do projeto .net 461 que eh a api, este projeto referência o .net standard 2.0 que não tem nada, neste exemplo

Comment: Conseguiu entender @LINQ ?

Comment: @JoãoRafaelColombo Manda o código do seu csproj no trecho que aponta o target framework

Comment: @LeandroAngelo pode olhar la no GitHub https://github.com/joaocolombo/WebApplication1

Answer (score 1):

Edite o ClassLibrary.csprj, e adicione o target da sua aplicação web.
lembrando que a tag fica no plural: TargetFramerowk**s**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]